# drag an image on a gridview item and get the position of the item on which the image is dragged

Tags: android

I have taken a GridView and added images and textview to it.
I am having an image below the gridView which can be dragged and dropped on the GridView.
My problem is that i am not able to retrieve the position of a particular item on which the image is dragged.

I would be thankful for your answers.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500972/how-to-get-the-position-of-an-item-when-dropped-in-a-gridview/57900522#57900522

Answer (score 0):

You didnt share all that much code, so its not easy to give you a specific solution to your problems. I will however assume you're using the onTouchEvent interface, if you are, when you drop the image, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, you need to store the x and y coordinates of where the image was dropped (event.getX() and event.getY()).

Then to get the position all you need to do is gridView.pointToPosition(X,Y).

Hope it helps in some way.